# Can I automatically (through an API) embed my LinkedIn posts on my website?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to automatically embed my LinkedIn posts on my website through an API (not manually), but everything I read seems to be evasive or outdated. Do they even have APIs?

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid there aren't for free, the only way to embed a feed that updates automatically on your website, is by paying:

SociableKit, 20 dolars per month
EmbedSocial, 30 dolars per month
TagEmbed, 20 dolars per month

Comment: The question itself is off-topic, and your answer is definitely off-topic: it has nothing to do with programming, and everything to do about product promotion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).